# How to implement top 10 leaderboard using Google Play Services C++

Tags: android, c++, ios, google-play-services, leaderboard

We are developing a game with a top-10 leaderboard for Android and iOS devices.

The game is written on C++ using cocos2d-x.

I have found methods to fetch current user's score, but no any method to fetch other users' score, or score lists.

Is it possible to fetch score for a list of users with Google Play Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using ScorePage.

ScorePage is a single data structure which allows you to access score data.
Data include Leaderboard id, start, timespan, collection, previous
score-page token, next score-page token, and the vector of all
score entries.

Methods to fetch ScorePage in LeaderboardManager:

```
void FetchScorePage(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the loadTopScores function documented here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html#loadTopScores%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, it's for java, not for C++.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch a `ScorePageToken` from the `LeaderboardManager`. The function you are looking for is this:

```
ScorePage::ScorePageToken gpg::LeaderboardManager::ScorePageToken(
                          std::string const& leaderboard_id,
                          LeaderboardStart  start,
                          LeaderboardTimeSpan time_span,
                          LeaderboardCollection collection) const
```

It allows you to get a token for you to feed it into `gpg::LeaderboardManager::FetchScorePage` or `gpg::LeaderboardManager::FetchScorePageBlocking`. Its signature is this:

```
void gpg::LeaderboardManager::FetchScorePage(
     ScorePage::ScorePageToken const& token,
     uint32_t max_results, 
     FetchScorePageCallback callback)
```

Its usage is like this:

```
auto token = gameServices->Leaderboards().ScorePageToken("LEADERBOARD-ID", TOP_SCORES, SOCIAL, ALL_TIME);
gameServices->Leaderboards().FetchScorePage(token, 10, 
    [=] (const gpg::LeaderboardManager::FetchScorePageResponse& response) {...});
```

Each page will return at most 25 score entries, but you can use the functions `NextScorePageToken` and `PreviousScorePageToken` to navigate through the entire leaderboard (in your case, it's not necessary, because you only want the top 10).